# Exchange 2010 smtp, encoding issue with japanese character utf-8

Tags: php, email, encoding, utf-8, exchange-server-2010

We are trying to deliver an email through an exchange 2010 SMTP server, the charset of the email is UTF-8.

We got some garbled japanese characters when using this SMTP, though we don't have this problem using gmail SMTP or sendgrid SMTP.

For example, 
this: `いただき、誠`

becomes `いただ=��、誠`

We are not sure if this is because gmail / sendgrid 's smtp are just converting our email to the right encoding automatically or if there is a detail we missed on the exchange 2010's smtp.

We also tried using Shift_JIS and ISO-2022-JP but we had the same problem.